# how to send an image in winsock2, using c

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winsock2

I am writing a very simple webserver in c (winsock2).

I am able to return the contents of my html pages.

Currently, what I am doing is writing the contents of a file into a char* buffer and sending it using "send()"

Although when I try to read an image (jpg, bmp), I can't write the characters into a buffer a some characters are "null" (0).

How can I send a whole image file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store null character in a `char*` buffer. You just have to use a counter to remember how many characters were written, instead of recomputing it by counting number of non-null characters (this can either be an integer or a pointer to the next point of insertion in the buffer).

To send a file, you'll do something like that:

```
int sendFile(int sock, const char* filename) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }

    off_t size = ftello(file);
    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }

    if (SendBinaryFileHeaderAndSize(sock, size) < 0) {
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[4096];
    for (;;) {
        size_t read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
        if (read == 0) {
            int retcode = 0;
            if (ferror(file))
                retcode = -1;
            fclose(file);
            return retcode;
        }

        for (size_t sent = 0; sent < read;) {
            int ret = send(sock, buffer + sent, read - sent, 0);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fclose(file);
                return -1;
            }

            assert(ret <= read - sent);
            sent += ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i know the size of the imagefile in c ? and once i know that can i use fgetc to fetch the contents from the image ?

also, I think i got the size from fseek. but when I open the image in the browser, the browser is just an empty page. there is nothing in it.

Comment: You can use `fseek(file, O, SEEK_END)`, or some platform specific code (`lstat`, `GetFileInformationByHandle`, ...), to get the size of the file. You also need to check that you send the correct header (size, content-type, ...) to your client following the HTTP protocol (you can use another webserver to check what it does send when you try to access an binary file).

Comment: I seem to able to read the file.
Although when I open it. I am able to download the file, but it says corrupt. Does fgetc return a signed char ? And does winsock.send allow unsigned chars to be transmitted ?

Comment: For a binary file, you should probably use `fread` to read whole block of it instead of reading it byte by byte with `fgetc` (this will be more efficient). The `send` function does not interpret the content of the buffer, it is transmitted as is, `fgetc` return a `int` (to be able to distinguish EOF from a simple character). So you have to take care when using the value as the `char` has been extended to `int` and the sign may have been propagated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes a very similar code worked for me.
Basically what I am doing now, is transmitting 3096 bytes of data until all the bytes are sent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how send() and fread() work. 0s in the buffer are not a problem for send or fread - they do not interpret their buffers as null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you load the image into your webserver, you would need to use either [Winsock:TransmitPackets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Winsock:TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also also wrapping the image in the appropriate HTTP headers

Note that these are MS specific extensions.

Also see [c++ - Bitmap transfer using winsock getdibits and setdibits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539874/bitmap-transfer-using-winsock-getdibits-and-setdibits)

Comment: could you give me some example code for TransmitPackets
I am using WindowsXP.

I am not too well versed with c.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on everything at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740632(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I read most of it. Could not find much on transmitting files.